# Spring : Parameter with that position did not exist exception

Tags: java, spring, date, jpa, exception

I am using Spring framework and in the following repository currentOrder method I send dates as a parameter but when I do this `Parameter with that position [1] did not exist` exception thrown 
I am sending following URL 
`http://localhost:3000/api/orders/search/currentOrder?fromDate=2017-04-28&toDate=2017-05-02`

Where is the mistake in my code?

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
     @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('rights')")
     @Query("Select o.orderDate from Order o where o.orderDate between fromDate and toDate")
     List<Order> currentOrder(@Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,@Param("toDate") Date toDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are not used in the query. Try instead mention them by `:paramName`

```
 @Query("Select o.orderDate from Order o where o.orderDate between :fromDate and :toDate")
 List<Order> currentOrder(@Param("fromDate") Date fromDate,@Param("toDate") Date toDate);
```

Could also reference `?#{fromDate}` See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

Comment: It Works :"D 
Thanks :')))))

Comment: Can I ask one more question to you?